# Should we have "topic" tags like food, people, places, etc.?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

I see there is a [food](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) tag, which is sort of a general topic that many vocabulary or word choice/usage questions would fall into. That got me thinking whether we should have "topic" tags like [food](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food), [people](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/people), [places](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/places), [transportation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation), etc. Does StackExchange have any guidelines on tags like these? What does English Language & Usage do? What should we do on SL&U?

Comment: A quick skim through EL&U's question list shows they really don't have "category" tags like this.

Comment: JL&U does though. EL&U doesn't have to be the leader, they definitely have differences from the non-English language L&U's. I personally like them and generally follow the food tags.

Comment: @hippietrail: Good point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like this idea.

The main caution I'd give is to be careful to [avoid meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). That is, tags that either don't tell you anything about the content of the question, tags that mean different things depending on who's reading the question.

In addition to that, make sure you don't fragment things so far that you end up with a lot of small, ultra-specific tags. For example, [parks](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parks) is probably too specific and a more general [places](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/places) is better.

I think using the same categories as you'd find in a language textbook would be a reasonable starting point.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll start adding general topic tags when they seem appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I think such topic tags are a good idea, and I've tried to encourage them on [French Language & Usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/) (and, in a slightly different but related setting, on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)). We have [society](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/societe), [economy](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economie), [dates](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dates), … (and similarly on SF&F [magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic), [aliens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens), …) When you're looking for a vocabularly question, it's easier to locate it in [food](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) than in some generic tag like [word-choice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice).